# How can I get all the string between two characters using regex?

Tags: javascript, python, regex

I have a text with this structure

- SourceName1: {desiredString1}
- SourceName2: {desiredString2}
- ...
- ...
- ...
- SourceNameJ: {desiredStringJ}

I would like to get whatever is between "{" and "}". I am using this Regex /(?<=<)(.*?)(?=>)/, but is only gives me back the first one and I want to get all of them.

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like you just want `re.findall(r'{(.*?)}', s)` no? (assuming you used the `python` tag because you wanted a python answer. It's not clear what you were expecting lookahead/behinds with `<` and `>` to do.

Comment: @3limin4t0r I guess you don't spend a lot of time with Python. The code I posted will result in a list of `['desiredString1', 'desiredString2', 'desiredStringJ']` given the OP's string.

Answer (score -1):

Is this about JavaScript or Python? Here is the JavaScript version:

```js
[
  'SourceName1: {desiredString1}',
  'SourceName2: {desiredString2}',
  'SourceName3: {desiredString3}',
].forEach(str => {
  let m = str.match(/\{(.*?)\}/);
  console.log(str + ' ==> ' + (m ? m[1] : '(not found)'));
});
```

Output:

```
SourceName1: {desiredString1} ==> desiredString1
SourceName2: {desiredString2} ==> desiredString2
SourceName3: {desiredString3} ==> desiredString3
```

Explanation:

- `\{` -- expect '{'
- `(.*?)` -- capture group with non-greedy scan
- `\}` -- expect '}'

In case you have a string where you want to extract multiple `{...}` patterns you can use this:

```js
const str = 'SourceName1: {desiredString1}, SourceName2: {desiredString2}, SourceName3: {desiredString3}';
let m = str.match(/\{(.*?)\}/g);
console.log(str + '\n==> matches: ' + JSON.stringify(m));
```

Output:

```
SourceName1: {desiredString1}, SourceName2: {desiredString2}, SourceName3: {desiredString3}
==> matches: ["{desiredString1}","{desiredString2}","{desiredString3}"]
```